# Find parent table tag from td

Tags: jquery, html-table

How do I get to the parent table tag from the `td` I am currently in?

I tried `.parents('table')` but that selects all tables outside the `td`, I just need the current one

Answer (score 101, accepted):

You need to use [`closest()`](http://api.jquery.com/closest/) function:

```
$('td').closest('table');
```

Answer (score 16):

Try this

```
$('#selector').parents("table:first");
```

Comment: $('#selector').closest('table')